# Similar Query Behaving Differently

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have 2 similar looking Queries giving 2 different result
,Not able to see the difference in query structure though

Query 1

```
UPDATE csv_Customer_Master,Customer_Master
SET
Customer_Master.Point_Balance=csv_Customer_Master.Point_Balance
WHERE csv_Customer_Master.Customer_Id = Customer_Master.Customer_Id
```

Query 2

```
UPDATE Customer_Master
SET Point_Balance = (
SELECT Point_Balance
FROM csv_Customer_Master
WHERE csv_Customer_Master.Customer_Id = Customer_Master.Customer_Id)
```

query 1 is updating `Customer_Master` for just the customers in `csv_Customer_Master` for `Point_Balance` nothing else

query2 is updating `Customer_Master` for the customers in `csv_Customer_master` and then updating rest of the `Point_Balance` column to 0 for all other customers in `Customer_Master`

To me both the queries are the same but not sure why all other customers are getting updated to 0
Column Type for Point_Balance is Decimal(15,2) Default -1

Answer (score 2):

In the first query the WHERE clause is filtering on the table being updated - so limits which records in that table are updated.

In the second query the WHERE clause is a filter in the calculation on the right of the '=' sign, so affects the value that Point_Balance is set to, not which records in Customer_Master are being updated

Comment: Does it mean that every row goes through filter and update at the same time ? sounds kinda wrong thing to happen because filtering should always happen first

Comment: I’m not clear what you are asking. The 2 queries are different, the WHERE clauses are doing very different things and they will be executed in the appropriate place in the respective execution plans for each query

Comment: I got it now , thanks for the answer , Tried out a few examples then understood well , thanks